# ERROR: COALESCE types bytea and character varying in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, coalesce

I write a postgresql and pass parameter `name1` from my java code with Spring + Hibernate.

```
SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE name = COALESCE(:name1, name2)
```

but i got an error

```
ERROR: COALESCE types bytea and character varying
```

The type of `name1` is String in my java code.

I tried to solve the problem

```
COALESCE(convert_from(:name1,'UTF8'), name2)
```

It will pass JUNIT Test in Eclipse. However when I run it on Tomcat, I will get an error

```
Error:convert_from(character varying, unknown) not exist
```

How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about Spring / Hibernate, but you need to *cast* both values to the same type. This has *not* a question of encoding. `SELECT * FROM Test WHERE name = COALESCE(cast(name1 AS text), cast(name2 AS text))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could I ask why `convert_from(character varying, unknown) not exist` happen? Since `COALESCE(convert_to(:name1,'UTF8'), name2)` works well on PgAdminIII. Thanks:)

Comment: AS you have mentioned "name1" is String, I believe "name2" will also be String. Are you using "Query" or "SQLQuery" hibernate interface for SQL execution? It should be SQLQuery.

Comment: Also, for setting parameter you need to use `.setParameter("name1", name1);` and not `.setString()`. setParameter() allows NULL as parameter values whereas .setString() does not.

Comment: Error message says 'convert_from' not found, and in pgadmin you use 'convert_to'

Comment: To Roman Konoval: I edit my post, thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solve my question.

```
SELECT * FROM Test
WHERE name = COALESCE(CAST(:name1 AS TEXT), name2)
```

Thank Erwin Brandstetter for giving me advise.